# Execute shell commands using nodejs with root access

Tags: node.js, shell, sudo

I want to execute the following shell commands inside a nodeJs application.
If i am doing the work manually, the commands are as following:

```
sudo su
password
1 command that needs a root access
exit
```

Any idea or a code snippet will be helpful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can combine all 4 commands into one by Ref: [Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/67766/224204)

```sh
echo "<password>" | sudo -S "<command that needs a root access>"
```

In your NodeJs code - try one of the following:

- Pure JS way

```js
var command='echo "<password>" | sudo -S "<command that needs a root access>"';
child_process.execSync(command)
```

- Using Library [shell-exec](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shell-exec) - helper library which uses child_process.spawn

```js
const shellExec = require('shell-exec')
var command='echo "<password>" | sudo -S "<command that needs a root access>"';
shellExec('echo Hi!').then(console.log).catch(console.log)
```

> Be sure to validate the command that need to be executed, before triggering execute to avoid unwanted results.

Comment: Some tips: 
if the password contains ! character u should use double quotes for the command and single quote for the password.
if the command contains echo u should put it in a bash file and call the bash file or you will get an error.

Answer (score 3):

While the accepted answer is good, it's not the most secure - as the sudo password is stored in plaintext.

A more secure way is to add a line to the sudoers file which will allow specific users to execute specific commands via sudo without a password being required:

```
user host = (root) NOPASSWD: cmd
```

Replace 'user', 'host', and 'cmd' with your requirements.

This avoids the need for any passwords to be stored in plaintext and, if you wrap up commands in shell scripts with appropriate validation, can strictly control superuser access.

For more details, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/159009) or the [sudoers manual](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html)

Answer (score -2):

You can execute commands using exec function of child_process

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");
// Here you can execute whatever command you want to execute 
exec("ls -la", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    // stdout returns the output of the command if you wish to use
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

Comment: The question being asked is about spawning processes with elevated privileges, but your answer does not elevate the privileges of the child process.